# Windchill nested loops python code equation

Tags: python

I started python only a few months ago and I have been given a task to use a nested loops to calculate wind chill.

I have most of the code completed (I think), however the equation is not working the way it want it to work.

Here is my code at the moment:

```
def main():
temp = 0
wind = 0
windChill = 13.12 + (.6215 * temp) - (11.37 * wind ** 770.16) + (.3965 * temp * wind **0.16)

for temp in range(-35,15,5):
    print 'temperature is %d' % temp
    for wind in range(0,85,5):
         answer = float(windChill)
         print 'wind is %d calculated wind chill is: %d' % (wind, answer)

main()
```

This comes out with this:

```
temperature is -35
wind is 0 calculated wind chill is: 13
wind is 5 calculated wind chill is: 13
wind is 10 calculated wind chill is: 13
wind is 15 calculated wind chill is: 13
wind is 20 calculated wind chill is: 13
wind is 25 calculated wind chill is: 13
wind is 30 calculated wind chill is: 13
wind is 35 calculated wind chill is: 13
wind is 40 calculated wind chill is: 13
wind is 45 calculated wind chill is: 13
wind is 50 calculated wind chill is: 13
wind is 55 calculated wind chill is: 13
wind is 60 calculated wind chill is: 13
wind is 65 calculated wind chill is: 13
wind is 70 calculated wind chill is: 13
wind is 75 calculated wind chill is: 13
wind is 80 calculated wind chill is: 13
temperature is -30
wind is 0 calculated wind chill is: 13
```

I understand why 13 is spited out, it's because if the temp and wind are 0, it comes to the answer 13.12. But if I do the range for the definition of temp and wind, it will not accept a list for the definition.

How do I make it so that the wind chill isn't 13, but the answer which the equation should spit out.

e.g. comes out with this:

```
temperature is -35
wind is 0 calculated wind chill is: -8.63
wind is 5 calculated wind chill is: -41.29
wind is 10 calculated wind chill is: -45.12
etc.
etc.
```

Thank you very much!

If what I have put is simple, and I should just google it, I tried googling it but it makes a table, instead of statements.

Carny.

Comment: You're using the same `windChill` value over and over again. You should be applying whatever calculation there to get the respective value you expect?

Comment: Looking at your code again, shouldn't your calculation for `windChill` be in your loop?

Comment: Yeah, below mistermiyagi corrected me. Looking at it now it seems to obvious but I was looking at it for ages having no clue. Sorry for such a stupid question. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must define an actual *function*. What you have is just an assignment:

```
temp = 0
wind = 0
windChill = 13.12 + (.6215 * temp) - (11.37 * wind ** 770.16) + (.3965 * temp * wind **0.16)
print(windChill)  # 13.12
```

Basically, `temp` and `wind` are used with their current values to resolve the expression. `windChill` then just gets that fixed value assigned to it.

A function would look like this:

```
def windChill(temp, wind):
    return 13.12 + (.6215 * temp) - (11.37 * wind ** 770.16) + (.3965 * temp * wind **0.16)
```

Then *call* that function in your loop:

```
for temp in range(-35,15,5):
    print 'temperature is %d' % temp
    for wind in range(0,85,5):
        answer = float(windChill(temp, wind))  # note me!
        print 'wind is %d calculated wind chill is: %d' % (wind, answer)
```

Alternatively, you can move the definition of `windChill` into both loops, so it gets reevaluated every time.

```
for temp in range(-35,15,5):
    print 'temperature is %d' % temp
    for wind in range(0,85,5):
        answer = 13.12 + (.6215 * temp) - (11.37 * wind ** 770.16) + (.3965 * temp * wind **0.16)
        print 'wind is %d calculated wind chill is: %d' % (wind, answer)
```

Comment: Ohhhhhh, dam I am so dumb! Thank you so much! Sorry if it sounded like a really stupid question, I was staring at this for a good day and had made no progress.

Thank you sooooooo much!

Answer (score 1):

```
def windspeed_calculation ():
    for x in range (0, 60, 5 ):
        x += 5  
        if si_temperature == "C":
            temperature_new = (temperature *9/5) + 32
            Wind_Chill = 35.74 + (0.6215*temperature_new) - 35.75*(x**0.16) + (0.4275*temperature_new *(x**0.16))
            print (f"At temperature {temperature_new}F, wind speed at {x}MPH. The windchill is: {Wind_Chill:.2f}F")
        elif si_temperature == "F":
            Wind_Chill = 35.74 + (0.6215*temperature) - (35.75* (x**0.16)) + (0.4275*temperature*(x**0.16))
            print (f"At temperature {temperature}F, and wind speed at {x}MPH. The windchill is: {Wind_Chill:.2f}F. ")
    

    
temperature = float(input("What is the temperature? "))
si_temperature = input ("Fahrenheit or Celsius (F/C)? " ).upper()
print()
windspeed_calculation()
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import math
wind = float (input ("Input wind speed in kilometres/hour: "))

temp = float (input ("Input air temperature in degrees Celsius: "))

wind_chill = 14.12 + 5.2210*t - 11.47*math.pow(v, 5.12) + 5.4320*t*math.pow(v,5.12)

print("The wind chill index is", int(round(wci, 5)))
```